# Catboost tuning order?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation, hyperparameters, catboost

So with Catboost you have parameters to tune and also iterations to tune. So for iterations you can tune using cross validation with the overfit detector turned on. And for the rest of the parameters you can use Bayesian/Hyperopt/RandomSearch/GridSearch. My question is which order to tune Catboost in. Should I tune the number of iterations first or the other parameters first. A lot of the parameters are kind of dependent on number of iterations, but also the number of iterations could be dependent on the parameters set. So any idea of which order is the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

You have essentially answered your own question already. Any variable that depends on something else `x` you must first define `x`.

One thing to keep in mind is you can define a function before the variables you need to pass into it since its only when you call the function that you need the input variables, defining the function is just setting the process you will use. Calling a function and defining the variable it returns is what you have to do in order.

The order you would use is:

Include any remote librarys or functions, define any initial variables that dont depend on anything, define your local functions.

Next in your main you first need to generate the variables that your iteration function requires, then itterate with these variables, then generate the ones that depend on the itteration.

Comment: The problem I'm thinking of is more along the lines of the fact that if you keep the iterations as the default number(500) and optimize the parameters you'll essentially be optimizing for 500 iterations and it'll make any other number of iterations worse, regardless if those other number of iterations would actually be an improvement.

Comment: You need to add your code to the question for me to comment on this, what sort of optimization are you doing? is it getting applied to a cost function? what is the cost function?